# List appending and web crawling difficulty in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am facing a difficulty in parsing the population count and appending it to a list
from bs4 import *
import requests

```
def getPopulation(name):
    url="http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/"+name+"-population/"
    data=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(data.text,"html.parser")
    #print(soup.prettify())
    x=soup.find_all('div',{"class":"col-md-8 country-pop-description"})
    y=x[0].find_all('strong')
    result=y[1].text
    return result

def main():
    no=input("Enter the number of countries : ")
    Map=[]
    for i in range(0,int(no)):
        country=input("Enter country : ")
        res=getPopulation(country)
        Map.append(res)
    print(Map)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The function works fine if i run it separately by passing a country name such as "india" as a parameter but shows an error when i compile it in this program.I am a beginner in python so sorry for the silly mistakes if any present.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Latheesh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Population Graph.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Latheesh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Population Graph.py", line 19, in main
    res=getPopulation(country)
  File "C:/Users/Latheesh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Population Graph.py", line 10, in getPopulation
    y=x[0].find_all('strong')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Wich is the country you are getting Error?

Comment: I tried india,china.No complex names but still i am finding an error.

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, please don't forget to accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It did work and thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code for the sample cases (india and china) and ran into no issue. The reason you'd get the indexerror is if there are no results for find_all, for which the result would be `[]` (so there is no 0th element).

To fix your code you need a "catch" to confirm there are results. Here's a basic way to do that:

```
def getPopulation(name):
    ...
    x=soup.find_all('div',{"class":"col-md-8 country-pop-description"})
    if x:
        y=x[0].find_all('strong')
        result=y[1].text
    else:
        result = "No results founds."
    return result
```

A cleaner way to write that, eliminating the unnecessary holder variables (e.g. y) and using a ternary operator:

```
def getPopulation(name):
    ...
    x=soup.find_all('div',{"class":"col-md-8 country-pop-description"})

    return x[0].find_all('strong')[1].text if x else "No results founds."
```

A few other notes about your code:

1. It's best to use returns for all of your functions. For main(), instead of using `print(Map)`, you should use `return Map`
2. Style convention in Python calls for variable names to be lowercase (e.g. Map should be map) and there should be a space before your return line (as in the shortened getPopulation() above. I suggest reviewing [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to learn more about style norms / making code easier to read.
3. For `url` it's better practice to use string formatting to insert your variables. For example, `"http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/{}-population/".format(name)`